# HP Spectre 13-3014tu Ultrabook - Subwoofer Beats Audio not working - IDT 92HD95

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have an HP Spectre 13-3014tu Ultrabook (G4X24PA#ABG) running Ubuntu 20.04, which includes Beats Audio in the form of 2 speakers and an integrated subwoofer. I can not get the subwoofer to work at all, and the sound is laughable compared to Beats on Windows 8. I have read many posts regarding this, that suggest to override the chip pin value in order to enable the LFE, but unfortunately, none of the configurations I found is applicable on my one that is the IDT 92HD95.

[The image shows the pins I can see using HDAJAckRetask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N8Lz.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: "*I have read many posts regarding this, that suggest to override the chip pin value...*" - you probably know more about this than us at this point, so can you catch us up to speed with your research and elaborate on this?  What did you hope to accomplish with "jack retasking"? Have you found out what audio adapter your laptop has and have you made sure that you are using the correct drivers?  I see that the device manufacturer publishes *no* linux drivers for the hardware: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Spectre-13-Ultrabook/5401166/model/7035336

Comment: Hi @nmath ,
as you mentioned, HP does not provide the drivers for Linux. However, there is a way to map manually the hardware properly. I think [this article] (https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/) is the one closer to the solution I am looking for. Unfortunately, the codec in that article is slightly different from mine and the pins do not match with it.

Comment: I also found this [patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/sound/pci/hda/patch_sigmatel.c). Could it be helpful to find the right setup?